# Grafana: one query, two outputs to percents values

Tags: grafana

I need a help with grafana: I have one query which returns 2 values, these values are represented in absolute values.

I would like to represent/plot my data as percent values.
Is there any way to convert it to percents ?

As I found there is `asPercents()` function, but it doesn't work for my grafana version ...

Answer (score 1):

A third option is using transformations from the transformation-tab (instructions see [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transform-data/add-transformation-to-data/)). You need one "Add field from calculation" where you make a binary operation S1 + S2, be sure to not activate "Replace all fields" here. Then you need a second "Add field from calculation" and binary operation where you devide S1 by the result of your first binary operation. Here you activate "Replace all fields" to remove S1, S2 and "S1+S2" from your graph. If you want to keep S1 and S2, add another transformation "Organize Fields", where you can select, which series have to be visible.

Now you have the resulting ration but it is in the range 0-1. To change it to 0-100 % add a field override to your result and choose "Percent (0.0-1.0)" from Standard options > Unit.

Comment: Disadvantage is that it may consume some Grafana resources (CPU/mem). Usually, TSDBs are better optimized for calculation on their own side.

Comment: I totally agree. But I wanted to outline this possibility as the transformations in grafana are a great tool for quick manipulation of your query results.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- calculate it with used datasource (TSDB), it looks like you have Graphite, so use `asPercents()` correctly: https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.asPercent
- visualize values as percent in the Grafana - some Grafana panels support that, for example `Time series` panel, where you need to enable `Stack series`: `100%`.

Comment: Hi Jan!
Many thanks for your answer !

Seems that ```asPercents()``` calculate percent among whole time series (the sum of all points in the wildcard series will be used as total), 
but I need something like ratio for each point of time: S1 / ( S1 + S2) * 100

and seems that I should modify my datasources

Comment: @EugeneDobrovlskyi so don't bother with option 1 and use option 2.